# SwiftUI- App does not conform to protocol 'App'

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment

I'm a beginner to programming and have just added a custom tab bar to allow navigation throughout the app. However, since I have added the property wrappers to let this happen I get the error:

> 'app does not conform to protocol 'App' '.

It forces me to add the init() protocol stubs but I cannot seem to get it to work- so I can run by code without the error 'Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties'. I've tried everything but still it won't go away.

I updated Xcode last night if that is relevant and the error has only come on as I started working on my project today.

Here's where the error is coming from

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct PhotoApp: App {

    init () {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(viewRouter)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `viewRouter`. The reason it gives you an error is that `PhotoApp` does not conform to `App`. This is because in the definition of the `App` protocol, the `init` is required:

```
/// Creates an instance of the app using the body that you define for its
/// content.
///
/// Swift synthesizes a default initializer for structures that don't
/// provide one. You typically rely on the default initializer for
/// your app.
init()
```

If you do not provide `viewRouter` a value, the memberwise initializer of the struct is used instead. It would be `init(viewRouter: ViewRouter)`, when we just want `init()`.

Without the `init()` setting a default value for `viewRouter` or by doing so directly, you got the error "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties".

The following will work for you:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct PhotoApp: App {

    init () {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter = ViewRouter()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(viewRouter)
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: Pass in anything the `init` of `ViewRouter` requires, if needed.*